# How can I set up Google Play game sign in?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I looked at the documentation and searched online for some tutorials, then saw that some where using `BaseGameActivity.java` and others not and now I've never been more confused, so I'll list my questions hoping that someone would clear things up to me (please don't respond with a documentation link only).

All I need is that the player automatically signs in at the start.

1) Does my game have to be published or do I have to insert some ID-s somewhere?(my game is on the developer console ready to be published).

2) What is the actual code that I have to write for the sign in function?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps that [Google Play Games Services docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) has already specified for you.

Step 1. Sign in to the Google Play Developer Console

Step 2. Add your game to the Google Play Developer Console

Step 3. Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID

Check the [GPGS Android Samples in Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) as well.

**What is the actual code that I have to write for the sign in function?**

How to [Implement Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) in Your Android Game

```
private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

// ...

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // Already resolving
        return;
    }

    // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
        mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

        // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
        // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
        // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
        // an issue with sign in, please try again later."
        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, R.string.signin_other_error)) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
    }

    // Put code here to display the sign-in button
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method.                                                                 and it points to the main class where the mGoogleApiClient.connect(); is